# Find an optional symbol from statically linked file with gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'd like to support some accelerated AVX/SSE functionality, but I'd like to be able to *optionally* include it.  I could use dlsym() along with a shared object, but I'm trying to avoid shared linkage if at all possible in the interest of more portable binaries.

Is there a mechanism I can use to use a static symbol if it's succesfully linked in, and otherwise fall back to a generic function?

Comment: (Not my downvote) - this sounds like an XY problem. You may want [Function mutliversioning](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a weak symbol, marked with `__attribute__ ((weak))`, declared like this:

```
void avx_function (void) __attribute__ ((weak));
```

And then you check for `NULL` before calling the function:

```
if (avx_function != NULL)
  avx_function ();
else
  fallback_implementation ();
```

But this doesn't really work for alternative implementations, only for optional functionality which is linked in by other means: You need a mechanism to actually pull in `avx_function` because the weak symbol will not do that.

But compile-time or link-time feature selection won't get you *portable binaries*.  You are likely better off with run-time checks and indirection through function pointers (for complex feature selection) if you need portable binaries.

Comment: I like this, but as you say portability's kind of hard (though I say portable and I mean between linux distros and intel/GCC compilers).

Answer (score 2):

If understand correctly, you have some linkage such as:

```
gcc -o prog main.o ...
```

in which some `avx_func` is called, and you'd like it to be so that
if `...` does not statically link the genuine definition of `avx_func` then it will statically link a generic surrogate.

If that's right, you can simply exploit the fact that the linker will resolve
a symbol to the first definition it finds in the linkage sequence, and will not
link any other definition unless it is forced to (in which case a multiple-definition
error is the usual result). So e.g.

**main.cpp**

```
extern void avx_func();

int main()
{
    avx_func();
    return 0;
}
```

**avx_or_not.cpp**

```
#ifdef HAVE_REAL_AVX
#include <iostream>

void avx_func()
{
    std::cout << "The real " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
#endif
```

**avx_fallback.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

void avx_func()
{
    std::cout << "The fallback " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

Make a static library `libavxfallback.a`:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -c avx_fallback.cpp
$ ar rcs libavxfallback.a avx_fallback.o
```

Compile the other source, assuming real AVX:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -DHAVE_REAL_AVX -c avx_or_not.cpp  main.cpp
```

Link a program:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o avx_or_not.o -L. -lavxfallback
```

Run:

```
$ ./prog
The real void avx_func()
```

Again compile the other source, this time assuming no real AVX:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -c avx_or_not.cpp  main.cpp
```

Relink and rerun:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o avx_or_not.o -L. -lavxfallback
$ ./prog
The fallback void avx_func()
```

At linktime, you do not need to know whether there is anything in the
linkage before `-lavxfallback` that calls `avx_func()`, or defines `avx_func()`:
you still know that if it is called, the first definition in the linkage will
be linked, and it will be the one in `libavxfallback` if there is no earlier one.